# JQuery three button click events executing on one click

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, jquery

Code generates HTML + JS for each tab. Now on each tab i have 2 buttons that are generated within HTML using PHP. It also generated Javascript onclick event for each button using JQuery.

this is the jquery click event for each button that is generated:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(document).on("click", ".mybutton", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).attr('whoami'));
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>'
```

now the two buttons that get generated by html have the following structure:

```
<button type="button" class="mybutton" whoami="button_1">First Button</button>
<button type="button" class="mybutton" whoami="button_2">Second Button</button>
```

now html and JS both generate fine i see both buttons fine, no JS errors nothing. I can click on both buttons but here is what happens:

When i click on First Button it alerts the following:

```
 button_1
 button_2
```

both button clicks get executed because they have same class name. How do i prevent both buttons being executed? I need only the clicked button to be executed and not all of them.

I tried adding **e.stopImmediatePropagation()** and this is what happens:

when i click on First Button i get alert correctly it only executes button_1 click, but when i click on Second Button it only executes button_1 click event instead of button_2.

Please help.

**NOTE:**
the reason i think it executes both is because there are 2 javascript parts that get appended to html and both scripts have on click event on **.button** but i cant change this code i need to somehow make sure only the clicked button gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that targeting the document click is what you want to be doing here.  What's the reasoning for not using:

```
$('.mybutton').on('click', function() {
  /* YOUR CODE HERE */
});
```

This would accomplish what you're looking for without forcing the larger context of the document into the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Write `click` event for particular button instead of `$(document)` click.

```
 <button type="button" class="mybutton" id="button_1">First Button</button>
 <button type="button" class="mybutton" id="button_2">Second Button</button>
```

JavaScript code should be :-

```
 $('#button_1').click(function(){
    //write your code here     

  }) 

  $('#button_2').click(function(){
    //write your code here     

  })
```

or you can also do by class name

```
  $('.mybutton').click(function(){
     var idval = $(this).attr('id');
     alert(idval);

    //on the basis of particular id you can perform desired operation here

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons are being dynamically generated, you probably need to in fact, use the event delegation pattern you have currently with:

```
$(document).on("click", ".mybutton", function(e) {...})
```

More about that here under 'Direct and delegated events': http://api.jquery.com/on/

Are you sure there isn't other code running that you didn't include? Your code seems fine as in this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8e3Gp/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using whoami as an attribute you can use id which would be a better idea.
For the click event of the buttons, you select just the collection of buttons using the shared className that they both have, and apply the clickhandler to that and then $(this) will be the specific button that was clicked. No need to return false either since you're already doing e.preventDefault().

```
$(function(){
  $('.mybutton').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});

<button type="button" class="mybutton" id="button_1">First Button</button>
<button type="button" class="mybutton" id="button_2">Second Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the following:

```
$(".mybutton:not(.bound)").addClass("bound").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("hello");
   return false;
});
```

alerts hello 1 time only instead of 2 times.